# Exception thrown Constructor Injection - AutoFac Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

I have an Autofac DI Container and use constructor injection to inject configuration settings into my SampleClass. The Configuration Manager class is created as a singleInstance so the same single instance is used.

```
public ConfigurationManager()
{
    // Load the configuration settings
    GetConfigurationSettings();
}

public SampleClass(IConfigurationManager configurationManager)
{
    _configurationManager = configurationManager;
}
```

I am loading the configuration settings from a App.config file in the constructor of the configuration Manager. My problem is i am also validating the configuration settings and if they are not in the App.config file a exception is thrown, which causes the program to crash. Which means I cant handle the exception and return a response.

I am doing this the wrong way? Is there a better way to load the configuration settings Or is there a way to handle the exception being thrown.

Edit

```
ConfigurationManager configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager();
configurationManager.GetConfigurationSettings();
//Try catch around for the exception thrown if config settings fail

//Register the instance above with autofac
builder.Register(configurationManager()).As<IConfigurationManager>().SingleInstance();


//Old way of registering the configurationManager
builder.Register(c => new ConfigurationManager()).As<IConfigurationManager>().SingleInstance();
```

Comment: That's too little details. The solution depends on the way you initialize the container, resolve the `SampleClass`, use it and so on. If you deal with asynchrony, synchronization or multi-threading, it's very difficult to give a generic advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing absolutely the right thing. Why? You are preventing the system from starting when the application isn't configured correctly. The last thing you want to happen is that  the system actually starts and fails later on. Fail fast! However, make sure that this exception doesn't get lost. You could make sure the exception gets logged.

One note though. The general advice is to do as little as possible in the constructor of a type. Just store the incoming dependencies in instance variables and that's it. This way construction of a type is really fast and can never really fail. In general, building up the dependency graph should be quick and should not fail. In your case this would not really be a problem, since you want the system to fail as soon as possible (during start-up). Still, for the sake of complying to general advice, you might want to extract this validation process outside of that type. So instead of calling `GetConfigurationSettings` inside that constructor, call it directly from the composition root (the code where you wire up the container) and supply the valid configuration settings object to the constructor of the `ConfigurationManager`. This way you -not only- make the `ConfigurationManager` simpler, but you can let the system fail even faster.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not sure what you mean bu "supply the valid configuration settings object to the constructor of the ConfigurationManager" ConfigurationManger is just a object which holds and validates the configuration settings.Do you mean create a instance of configurationManager before i set up the DI container. Validate the parameters and if they are valid supply that instance to the DI container. See updated main answer

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is that you are mixing the composition and execution of your object graph by doing some execution during composition. In the DI style, constructors should be as simple as possible. When your class is asked to perform some meaningful work, such as when the `GetConfigurationSettings` method is called, that is your signal to begin in earnest.

The main benefit of structuring things in this way is that it makes everything more predictable. Errors during composition really *are* composition errors, and errors during execution really *are* execution errors.

The timing of work is also more predictable. I realize that application configuration doesn't really change during runtime, but let's say you had a class which reads a file. If you read it in the constructor during composition, the file's contents may change by the time you use that data during execution. However, if you read the file during execution, you are guaranteed to avoid the timing issues that inevitably arise with that form of caching.

If caching is a part of your algorithm, as I imagine it is for `GetConfigurationSettings`, it still makes sense to implement that as part of execution rather than composition. The cached values may not have the same lifetime as the `ConfigurationManager` instance. Even if they do, encoding that into the constructor leaves you only one option, where as an execution-time cache offers far more flexibility *and* it solves your exception ambuguity issue.

Answer (score -1):

I would not call throwing exceptions at composition-time a good practice. It is so because composition might have a fairly complex and indirect execution logic making reasonable exception handling virtually impossible. I doubt you could invent anything better than awful

```
try
{
  var someComponent = context.Resolve<SampleClass>();
}
catch
{
  // Yeah, just stub all exceptions cause you have no idea of what to expect
}
```

I'd recommend redesigning your classes in a way that their constructors do not throw exceptions unless they do really really need to do that (e.g. if they are absolutely useless with a null-valued constructor parameter). Then you'll need some methods that initialize your app, handle errors and possibly interact with user to do that.